# Sdl 1.3: how to inplement simple scale-9-grid for image resize?

Tags: c++, c, sdl, nine-patch, scale9grid

We have an image like:

[image]

We have 4 coordinates top:10, bottom:10, left:10, right:10 we have resize to values like newWidth:100, newHeight:35 we have some `SDL_Rect Sprite` which was generated from some `SDL_Surface *button` how to performe on that Sprite such resize transformations?

So how to inplement 9-slice scaling in SDL?

Answer (score 3):

I've made a demo project performing 9 slice rendering using [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [sdl-2](/questions/tagged/sdl-2) here: https://github.com/cxong/sdl2-9-slice

[image: screenshot]

Take a look at the `render()` function and copy it if you like - it's permissively licensed.

The key is to use the `srcrect` and `dstrect` parameters of [`SDL_RenderCopy()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy) - the former is which part of the source texture to render, the latter which part of the destination (render target) to render into.

For 9 slice, the corners are copied as-is; for the middle parts, depending on how you want to render - stretched or repeated - the `srcrect` will be the same, but `dstrect` will stretch or repeat.

Another thing is that [SDL does not do texture repeating](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136792/26250) (yet). So if you want to render as repeat mode, you need to use a loop.

Here's the function in case the project dies:

```c
int render(
    SDL_Renderer *renderer, SDL_Surface *s, SDL_Texture *t,
    int x, int y, int top, int bottom, int left, int right, int w, int h,
    bool repeat)
{
    const int srcX[] = {0, left, s->w - right};
    const int srcY[] = {0, top, s->h - bottom};
    const int srcW[] = {left, s->w - right - left, right};
    const int srcH[] = {top, s->h - bottom - top, bottom};
    const int dstX[] = {x, x + left, x + w - right, x + w};
    const int dstY[] = {y, y + top, y + h - bottom, y + h};
    const int dstW[] = {left, w - right - left, right};
    const int dstH[] = {top, h - bottom - top, bottom};
    SDL_Rect src;
    SDL_Rect dst;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        src.x = srcX[i];
        src.w = srcW[i];
        dst.w = repeat ? srcW[i] : dstW[i];
        for (dst.x = dstX[i]; dst.x < dstX[i + 1]; dst.x += dst.w)
        {
            if (dst.x + dst.w > dstX[i + 1])
            {
                src.w = dst.w = dstX[i + 1] - dst.x;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                src.y = srcY[j];
                src.h = srcH[j];
                dst.h = repeat ? srcH[j] : dstH[j];
                for (dst.y = dstY[j]; dst.y < dstY[j + 1]; dst.y += dst.h)
                {
                    if (dst.y + dst.h > dstY[j + 1])
                    {
                        src.h = dst.h = dstY[j + 1] - dst.y;
                    }
                    const int res = SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, t, &src, &dst);
                    if (res != 0)
                    {
                        return res;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unstable code, Although this works but for some platform this might give problems, like crash/freeze etc, Tried in webassembly not working.